# jQuery replace spaces in word

Tags: jquery

I have an `select` on my page with the `value` of `Test One`

`<option value="Test One">Test One</option>`

I wondered if there was a way to replace spaces in words using jQuery

I'm aware of the jQuery Trim technique but this only gets rid of spaces at the beginning and end and i'm looking for something to remove the spaces so it becomes `TestOne`

Any ideas?

Comment: it's not an `input` it's `select` and known as "Drop Down List".

Comment: @Shadow sorry my bad I was originally using an input but then change to a select - Thanks :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A simple `string.replace` will do the trick:

```
var str = "Test One";
str = str.replace(/ /g, '');
```

Now with regards to your question, this is where it gets a little confusing. If you want to replace the *value attribute*, then:

```
$('option').val(function (i, value) {
    return value.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

If you want to replace the *text between the tags*, then:

```
$('option').text(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

Comment: Not really. It will replace only the first space.. `Test One Two` will become `TestOne Two`.

Comment: @Shadow, fair enough. I just went straight off the example in the question. Changed it now.

Comment: how would you remove commas and the "&" symbol as well?

Answer (score 14):

To remove all spaces:

```
var str = $(selector).val();
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

In JavaScript `replace` only catches the *first* space, so to replace more you need a tiny regular expression. If you're only expecting a single space or none, `replace(' ', '')` should work well.

Comment: Why did you delete the answer then wrote it again? It causes the answer count to be wrong until cron job runs tonight.. ;)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I got confused about `replace`, but then rechecked and confirmed you need a regex to replace more than a single character.