# Get text from HTML Table and place it in a pre-defined string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

How can I get the value of the first TD and place it in a pre-defined string in jquery?

My try:

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

How can I put the value now in the following string as parameter and maybe remove the white spaces and add the dot between?

String: `{{email_open::john.sample@mymail.com}}John Sample{{email_close}}`

I thought I need the wrap Function in Jquery or am I wrong?

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Sample</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and [`trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) to remove space and lower the text:

```
var namemerge= $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
```

to replace the space in between word you can use regex like suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932898/jquery-replace-spaces-in-word) and append the mail suffix:

```
namemerge= namemerge.replace(/ /g, '.')+'@mymail.com';
```

```js
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var namemerge= $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
    console.log(namemerge);
    namemerge= namemerge.replace(/ /g, '.')+'@mymail.com';
    console.log(namemerge);
});
// I believe you can continue from this
console.log('{{email_open::john.sample@mymail.com}}John Sample{{email_close}}');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>John Sample</td>
</tr>
</table>
```